# How does the build process in Arduino IDE work for ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, ide, avr-gcc

How does the build process for esp8266 work in arduino IDE. Arduino ide uses avr-gcc to compile programs For atmel micro controllers. Does it uses same for compiling programs for esp8266?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it uses same for compiling programs for esp8266 ?.

No. It uses `xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc`. The compiler has to match the architecture.

Most of the build "process" (as in the actions that are taken) is the same, but executables specific to the EXP8266's XTensa core are used. There's also a few extra things in there, like building the (optional) SPIFFS image, etc.

Comment: What about uploading code to the board, does it use avrdude for that. Is uploading process same for various boards like nodeMCU or wemos D1.

Comment: No, it uses the *ESP8266 specific program*, called esptool.  *Every* executable run is the ESP8266 specific one.